# Creating and initialising a list of objects and assigning them values from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class with the attributes `name` and `address`. I need to create several instances of that class using a dictionary of the format `{name:age}`. The name and address of each object should come from the dictionary elements.

I am using Python 3.2.

Comment: This is extremely unclear, please add more details and post what the dictionary looks like.

Comment: I tried to clarify your question based on [Tim Pietzcker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11397639/577088)'s answer. But it's still very confusing that your objects have `address`es but your dictionary keys have `age`s. Which is it? Or is it both?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
>>> d = {"Mark": 32, "Jack": 25, "Jane":30}
>>> class Person():
...     def __init__(self,name,age):
...         self.name = name
...         self.age = age
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "{0} is {1} years old.".format(self.name, self.age)
...
>>> a = [Person(name,age) for name, age in d.items()]
>>> print(a[0])
Jane is 30 years old.
```